# Cron job not able to establish connection with postgresql database

Tags: shell, unix, cron, psql

I have tried to run the cron job with the following shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/opt/someApp/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

gsutil cp gs://api-bucket/order_status.csv order_status.csv

psql -d  apidb -U apidb  << EOF

DELETE FROM apidbgermany.order_status;
\copy apidb.order_status from '/u01/app/postgres/data/silver01/order_status.csv'  delimiter ',' CSV ;
EOF
```

My cronjob looks like this.

```
* * * * * /u01/app/postgres/data/silver01/order_status.sh &>/tmp/mycommand.log
```

[image: getting following error]

But if i execute the shell file manually in command line it is working great.

Comment: is it a local cron or remote ? and can you share the job error.

Comment: @RajVerma it is in remote Linux server . I have shared the error in the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access remote server you should execute command `psql` on this way:

```
psql -h postgress_host -d  apidb -U apidb  << EOF
....
```

otherwise `psql` try to connect local server. And when create cron scripts always use fill path to the executables

```
/usr/bin/psql ....
```

(for example)

and add as second line of your script line like:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

depend on where your environment settings are

Comment: Actually my cron job in remote server where postgres is installed. Not in my local machine

Comment: @PraveenkumarBeedanal, ok, but the error say script can't connect to instance. Did you exec the cron as PostgreSQL user?

Comment: i have created the shell script file inside postgresql user. Like i have used ´sudo su´ and then `su - postgres` and there i have created the file

Comment: @PraveenkumarBeedanal, is it postgres who run the cron? And will edit my answer to add one more thing

Comment: here postgres host is not local?. Because it is running in this machine only.

Comment: @PraveenkumarBeedanal, set the environment and try w/o host.

Comment: it is worked, thanks a lot. i have added port number also, because my port was 60901

Answer (score 1):

Also, please user pg_cron extension directly that will solve this problem for you. you can setup crons from inside of postgres.
[pg_cron extension](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron)

Comment: okay, you mean i have to use pg_cron insde '[postgres@dapih1pgs62 silver01]' postgres right?

Comment: the doc has it all, just follow the instructions there, but you have to install that extension if that is not a roadblock for you.

Comment: actually it is asking for postgres password to install this, but i have used 'su -postgres' before that

Comment: follow this https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron/issues/21  or just follow the "Installing pg_cron" part of this : https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron

Answer (score 0):

That error message is asking if the PostgreSQL server is running and because it is NOT it is generating that error message. The way I have had to use to eliminate that error is to run the following command: "sudo pg_ctlcluster (PG version number) main start" or sudo pg_cltcluster 11 main start" because I am using version 11 of PG.